# jQuery store selected checkboxes into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

**background**

I have a table grid of checkboxes, grouped by name, and each checkbox contains a time value. An example of the HTML:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="10am"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="11am"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="12pm"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="1pm"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="2pm"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="3pm"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="4pm"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="5pm"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="6pm"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" value="7pm"></td>
```

When the form is submitted, the values are `POST`ed how I want them to be; all the checked times are in the `tuesday[]` array.

**problem**

I want to do some client-side validation with `jQuery`. I want to check that at least one checkbox is checked.

I have tried storing it into a var like so:

```
var availTuesday  = $("input:checkbox[name='tuesday']:checked");
```

But when I do so and the `console.log(availTuesday);`, nothing is shown (regardless on if something is checked or not). I have also tried `console.log(availTuesday.serialize());`

**Question:**

how can I retrieve the user-checked values for the `tuesday[]` checkbox group, as well as for the other dates (`wednesday[]`, `thursday[]`, etc)?

Thank you.

Comment: you name in the selector doesn't match the name of the checkbox.

Comment: jQuery doesn't *parse* the `[]` outside of [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). The brackets should be included in the selector. `[name='tuesday[]']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector is not correct, change it to:

```
var $tuesday = $("input[type=checkbox][name='tuesday[]']:checked");
```

For getting the values you can use `.map()` method which returns an array:

```
if ($tuesday.length) {
   // Getting values of the checked checkboxes
   var values = $tuesday.map(function(){
        return this.value;
   }).get();
   // ...
} else {
    // There is no checked `day[]` checkbox
}
```

In case that you have other similar set of checkboxes you can use an array:

```
var days = ['days', 'in', 'a', 'week'],
    values = {},
    errors = [],
    $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");

$.each(days, function(_, day) {
  var $set = $checkboxes.filter('[name="'+day+'[]"]:checked');
  if ($set.length) {
      values[day] = $set.map(function() {
          return this.value;
      }).get();
  } else {
      // There is no checked `day[]` checkbox
      errors.push(day);
  }
});

if (errors.length) {
   // console.log('Please check at least one hour in ' + errors.join(', ') + ' days ...');
} else {
  // console.log(values);
}
```

Comment: lot of great answers here so it was hard to pick a best, but I think I learned the most from your post, so thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var availTuesday = [];
    $('input[type=checkbox][name="tuesday[]"]:checked').each(function() {
       availTuesday.push($(this).val()); 
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gxyg/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual `value`

```
var values = $("input[type=checkbox][name='tuesday[]']:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are really after is if any boxes are selected you can do the following:

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"][name="tuesday[]"]:checked').length) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

The `length` value is a property of the jQuery object (superset of DOM object) that specifies how many nodes matched the selector. In this case, if you check the length and the value is 0, no `:checked` checkboxes with the name `tuesday[]` exist (i.e. the user has not checked any boxes so display your validation message). It's quick and dirty validation. If you're looking to retrieve the values, the multitude of other answers are probably better.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fix the selector to match the name, as others have mentioned.
If you just want to test that one is checked, you can go straight to a boolean, like this:

```
var availTuesday  = $("input:checkbox[name='tuesday[]']:checked").length > 0;
```